# Problem with aws-sdk while creating S3 Buckets nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am currently using `aws-sdk` in order to list and create buckets.

My code is as follows

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const router = require('express').Router();

require('dotenv').config();

AWS.config.logger = console;

// AWS.config.update({region: process.env.AWS_REGION}); // AWS bucket region 
s3 = new AWS.S3({
    // apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION
}); // s3 svc object

// Accepts Bucket Name, Bucket Created User/ Belonging Organization
router.post('/create', (req, res, next)=>{
    var bucketParams = {
        Bucket: req.body.bucket
    }
    console.log(process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID);
    s3.createBucket(bucketParams, (err, data)=>{
        console.log("sample");
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
          } else {
            console.log("Success", data.Location);
          }
    })
});

router.get('/', (req, res, next)=>{
    s3.listBuckets((err, data)=>{
        if(err){

        }else{

        }
    })
});
```

The AWS IAM user policy that I use for these are as follows.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is, whenever I submit a http request, the request doesn't get terminated or return a valid response.

For an example.

I get the followings for creating a bucket named `sample-1`

```
[AWS s3 409 1.052s 0 retries] createBucket({
  Bucket: 'sample1',
  CreateBucketConfiguration: { LocationConstraint: 'eu-west-1' }
})
sample
Error BucketAlreadyExists: The requested bucket name is not available. The bucket namespace is shared by all users of the system. Please select a different name and try again.
    at Request.extractError (/home/caesar/Workspace/res-s3/res-s3-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:837:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/home/caesar/Workspace/res-s3/res-s3-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/home/caesar/Workspace/res-s3/res-s3-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/home/caesar/Workspace/res-s3/res-s3-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/home/caesar/Workspace/res-s3/res-s3-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/caesar/Workspace/res-s3/res-s3-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /home/caesar/Workspace/res-s3/res-s3-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/caesar/Workspace/res-s3/res-s3-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/caesar/Workspace/res-s3/res-s3-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/home/caesar/Workspace/res-s3/res-s3-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'BucketAlreadyExists',
  region: 'us-east-1',
  time: 2020-08-18T15:24:22.974Z,
  requestId: '3C1F8277A6CAD712',
  extendedRequestId: 'bfRp36yH8Gh64zjM5VrUqCJi0V1AY5Sc5Snpf5yROPyV0HHgWTtE7gIEz70HRHb2JoOcO6jfLvQ=',
  cfId: undefined,
  statusCode: 409,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 5.386495440613426
}
```

The strangest thing is that there is no bucket with the same name and the region which I used in this case had been `eu-west-1`. Anyone have any clue on why this happens and why the requests are not getting terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bucket names are global to AWS. see below

> Amazon S3 bucket names must be unique globally. If you get the "Bucket name already exists" or "BucketAlreadyExists" error, then you must use a different bucket name to create the bucket. These error messages indicate that another AWS account owns a bucket with the same name.

You should try using a unique name.